# Map where type of value is determined by key

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a Map where when I call the `.get(key)` function, the return type of this would be dependent on the key. Below is an example of what I mean

```
type target<Entity> = {
  type: Entity;
  name: string;
}

type indexType<Entity> = [
  target<Entity>,
  keyof Entity
]
declare class DataLoader<K, V,> { // Random class with properties
  constructor(/* ... */);
  ///...
}

const myMap = new Map<indexType<any>, DataLoader<any, any>>();

const thing: target<string> = {
  type: 'pokemon',
  name: 'bla'
}
const anotherThing: target<number> = {
  type: 42,
  name: 'sheesh'
}

myMap.set([thing, 'type'], new DataLoader<string, string>(/* ... */))
myMap.set([anotherThing, 'name'], new DataLoader<number, number>(/* ... */))

const res = myMap.get([thing, 'type']) // return type is any ! should be string !
```

I would like for typescript to know that for the input `[thing, 'type']` the return type of the get function will always be a `string`. Is this possible?

Comment: The return value will actually be `undefined`

Comment: Your map keys are arrays (objects), so they are stored and compared by reference.

Comment: Is there a different library other than `Map` that I could use where this would work?

Comment: Is this question fundamentally different from [your other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74179891/2887218)? If so could you [edit] one or both to clarify the difference? If not, could you delete one of them?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for pointing it out - I forgot to delete the other one yesterday, did so now though.